# What's the name of this theme for Visual Studio2012 in this pic

Tags: visual-studio-2012, colors, ide, themes

Just as the question asked, I want to get the name so I can search it, or give me a url to download it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012 go tools - option in Environment - General change your theme and color

[image: vs 2012]

you can Download Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor for more themes including good old VS2010 theme.